# How to paste string and int from map to an array in hive?

Tags: hive

I am trying to paste a `string` and `int` from `map` in `Hive` to an `array`.
For now, record looks like this:

```
{"string1":1,"string2":1,"string3":15}
```

Is there a way to convert it to an array like this:

```
["string1:1","string2:1","string3:15"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your map is called "M" and you want your array field to be called "A"

```
SELECT 
...
array(concat_ws(":","string1",M[1]),
      concat_ws(":","string2",M[2]),
      concat_ws(":","string3",M[3]) as A
....
FROM table;
```